# How to output the temporary table's values upon INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @NewLoan TABLE (
[MemberSSN]         varchar(11),
[VolumeID]      int,
[LoanDate]         datetime
)
INSERT INTO LOAN (MemberSSN, VolumeID, LoanDate) OUTPUT inserted.MemberSSN, inserted.VolumeID, 
inserted.LoanDate INTO @NewLoan
VALUES ('488-40-', 6, GETUTCDATE())
```

The point of it because the `LOAN` table has a trigger and I can't `OUTPUT` without putting the data `INTO` a temporary table. Now, instead of the message "(1) row has been added" after executing the query, I would like to `SELECT` the content of the `@NewLoan` table and see what has been added. How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT * FROM @NewLoan;`...? Also, that's not a temporary table, that's a Table Variable. Table Variables and Temporary Tables are quite different objects.

Comment: @Larnu wow...it's pretty embarassing. I could have sworn that I tried it but was giving me an error. Thanks a lot, nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want your front end to read it, then you can use whatever method returns a resultset to run the query:

```
DECLARE @NewLoan TABLE (
[MemberSSN]         varchar(11),
[VolumeID]      int,
[LoanDate]         datetime
);
INSERT INTO LOAN (MemberSSN, VolumeID, LoanDate)
OUTPUT inserted.MemberSSN, inserted.VolumeID, inserted.LoanDate INTO @NewLoan
VALUES ('488-40-', 6, GETUTCDATE());
SELECT * FROM @NewLoan
```

If this is being used in e.g. C# then ExecuteReader it, or DataAdapter.Fill, or Dapper.Query etc..

Comment: Exactly! That's what it was used for.

Comment: You can also skip th table variable and do `INSERT INTO t (cols) VALUES(vals); SELECT * FROM t WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` though I must admit I'm kinda confused in your case; you seem to know everything except the date - was all this really just to select the date from the server? I would have expected the output clause to output a primary key that you didn't know (assuming SSN is not the PK) which is why we normally use some construct like this from C#; send some values to the DB, download all values from the DB including generated PK, dates, or other things etc

Comment: The SSN is indeed a primary key. I want to return these two values so, eventually, when the UI is done, I will output the book and to whom it was loaned. Thanks for the tip, though! Makes the query much, much cleaner.

Comment: No probs! It's good for single inserts, of course; your original way would be needed if you were doing multi row inserts eg `INSERT INTO t SELECT cols FROM otherT WHERE ...` and a select that causes 10 rows to be inserted etc. If you know the PK of course, then you can select using it instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY (which is typicall;y used for generated identities not known to the inserting application)